# Why do my cakephp url's have 'index.php' after the domain?

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes

I've created nice re-directs like this: 
https://www.lessonshark.com/sign-up

Currently my url's look like this:
https://www.lessonshark.com/index.php/sign-up

I am aware that this may be an issue outside of Cakephp, but have no clue where to start with this.

As a small hint, the application has been moved from a Linode Virtual server to an IntoVPS virtual server. On the old Linode server, the routing worked perfectly. On the IntoVPS server the 'index.php' shows up.

Any ideas on how to get rid of the 'index.php' portion? Or even how to investigate what is causing the 'index.php' to show up in the first place?

Comment: how does your htaccess look like? what is your cake version? and are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you have setup mod_rewrite to work with CakePHP. Check the installation guides: [1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Installation.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess), [2.0](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#apache-and-mod-rewrite-and-htaccess)